# How to integrate with Drupal migrate to create a periodic import into CiviCRM?

Tags: drupal, import

We have a requirement to periodically update a set of contacts in the CRM from an external source. Our preferred base technology is Drupal migrate. This is so that we can automate some transforms and the user can trigger the imports as well as review the results. It's also so that we don't run into the performance limits that we typically do with the CiviCRM import procedure.

Which module is the best option for creating the CiviCRM integration?

1. [civicrm_migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_migrate)
2. [civimigrate](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civimigrate)
3. [civicrm_entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity)

Answer (score 4):

I would expect 2/ ie https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civimigrate which we have made lots of use off for migrating legacy data. From memory we have one situation where client can 'click a switch' to run a migration to pull in latest data. I will flick a note to eileen to see if she can expand

Comment: yep - that's the module I'd use

Comment: Can you provide any pros and cons of the civimigrate module over the others? Are more entities supported? Is rollback fully supported?